# How to play flash files in webview of native android app

Tags: android, flash

I am trying to render a webview inside native android app.
My webview consists of many flash files(having ".swf" extention).

The flash plugin is not initialized and a black screen appears.

Is there any way to enable flashplayer or any additional player which will solve my problem.

Note: Please don't suggest to convert flash files to html5 supported format. Also, the files plays well in dolphin browser.